# How to clear the first interval value after the second interval value is generated

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a function that will generate value continously every two seconds after button clicked.

If button clicked 2 times the function with generate 2 value and so on.

I'm using `clearInterval` at the second click and so on to avoid duplicate value.

```js
var clickValue = 0;
function func() {
  var value = 0;
  var generateValue = function() {
    value = value + 1;
    console.log('value: ' + value);
  }
  
  var startInterval = setInterval(generateValue, 2000);
    
  clickValue = clickValue + 1;
  console.log(clickValue + ' click');

  if (clickValue > 1) {
    clearInterval(startInterval);
    console.log('Interval on ' + clickValue + ' click cleared');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func()">Click</button>
```

If we run the code above, it just clear the second interval and so on. The value of the first interval still running.

Result i expected :

```
1 click
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
2 click
Interval on 1 click cleared
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
3 click
Interval on 2 click cleared
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
```

How to clear the first interval value after second clicks and start the second interval value and so on like result above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```js
var clickValue = 0;
var value = 0;
var startInterval;
function func() {
  var generateValue = function() {
    value = value + 1;
    console.log('value: ' + value);
  }
  
  startInterval = setInterval(generateValue, 2000);
    
  clickValue = clickValue + 1;
  console.log(clickValue + ' click');

  if (clickValue > 1) {
    clearInterval(startInterval);
    console.log('Interval on ' + (clickValue-1) + ' click cleared');
    value = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You should call **clearInterval** before setting **setInterval** other wise it will always clear last interval only.

Comment: This doesn't clear the first interval, it clears the newly created interval (and just says it cleared the first one in a log message). The first one is still running. To clear the previous interval instead `startInterval = setInterval(generateValue, 2000);` should be moved to after the if statement with the `clearinterval` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
var clickValue = 0;
var startInterval;
function func() {
  var value = 0;
  var generateValue = function() {
    value = value + 1;
    console.log('value: ' + value);
  }

  clearInterval(startInterval);

  startInterval = setInterval(generateValue, 2000);

  clickValue = clickValue + 1;
  console.log(clickValue + ' click');

  if (clickValue > 1) {
    console.log('Interval on ' + (clickValue-1) + ' click cleared');
  }
}
```

Here value will be new for each click.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var clickValue = 0;
var lastId = null;

function func() {
  // clear last interval
  clearInterval(lastId);
  console.log('Interval on ' + clickValue + ' click cleared')
  
  clickValue++;
  console.log(clickValue + ' click');
 // start new interval
  var value = 0;
  lastId = setInterval(function () {
    value++;
    console.log('value: ' + value);
  }, 2000)
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func()">click</button>
```

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.